# Yahoo finance API returns different values

Tags: yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, stocks

I'm using `yahoo.finance.quotes` but the values I get for **FDC** are different than when I search for **FDC** plus one more.

[**FDC** and **GOOG**](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22FDC,GOOG%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=): then **FDC** `Change: -0.55`

[ONLY **FDC**](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22FDC%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=): **FDC** `Change: +0.41`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been reported by others that the data is both delayed and inconsistent.

For example if you refresh, and inspect the "LastTradeWithTime" key value, you get different quotes from different times of day, for no apparent reason.

In your example the data is from 13-Jun vs 14-Jun.